# how to detect whether strings are not captured for localization in .po files i.e no equivalent entry are in all local files

Tags: cakephp, localization

Hi we have some queries regarding localization/.po files

1> We want to detect the missing strings or strings which are not being captured for L10N. how we can detect that? is that any method or command to update the strings

2> Locale files (.po) for "cn-zh" or another Locale are not complete (missing strings)

3> String has been captured for L10N but does not have a matching pair in .po files

Comment: According to QA perspective how can we test the missing strings in the localization file.
Is there any kind of tool to detect the missing strings in .po files?

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`msgmerge`](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/msgmerge-Invocation.html) is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the i18n shell to extract all the translatable strings from your application into a `.pot` file:

```
$ /path/to/cake/console/cake i18n help --app /path/to/app
```

Or, if you put /path/to/cake/console/ in your `$PATH` environment variable and `cd` to your app directory:

```
$ cake i18n help
```

Comment: Yes, you can find directions on how to use the CakePHP shell here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/108/The-CakePHP-Console (Although the i18n shell is not documented in the book, it is part of CakePHP: http://api.cakephp.org/class/i18n-shell)